# Gradient in Safari 5.0.2 is not working

Tags: css

I have a problem in css gradient on safari 5.0.2 . the css code is working on safari 5.1 but in 5.0, its not working. Why is this happening? Any Idea?

Here is my code:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #D82102, #B90602);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #D82102, #B90602);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #D82102, #B90602);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #D82102, #B90602);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #D82102, #B90602);
```

Did I forget something? please help me. It stuck me.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1e5799), color-stop(50%,#2989d8), color-stop(51%,#207cca), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8));
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you did not included all vendor specific gradients properties.

Missing vendor-prefixed CSS gradients for Firefox 3.6+, Old Webkit (Safari 4+, Chrome), Opera 11.1+

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0)));
```

You are only using **webkit-linear-gradient** and **linear-gradinet**.

Answer (score 1):

Safari 5.0 does not support CSS gradients. Only 5.1 and later support it. You can check it out here on w3 schools-
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

On the other hand the apple-safari website page says that gradients are supported in versions 4.0 and above. It also mentions how to use them-
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007955-SW25

Comment: Just like on apple website, can i use it states that the property is patially supported. Anyway i use w3 schools as it is more trustworthy and safer to check the supported versions of a css property. I would have tested the code normally before answering a question but i cant in this case as i am running on windows..... @Jonathan

Answer (score 1):

To get a linear gradient to work in all supporting browsers

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(black, white); /* FF 3.6+ */  
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #000000), color-stop(100%, #ffffff)); /* Safari 4+, Chrome 2+ */  
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(black, white); /* Safari 5.1+, Chrome 10+ */  
background: -o-linear-gradient(black, white); /* Opera 11.10 */  
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#ffffff'); /* IE6 & IE7 */  
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#ffffff')"; /* IE8+ */  
background: linear-gradient(black, white); /* the standard */
```